# Which way to create cookie, by frontend or backend?

Tags: javascript

Per I understand, cookie is some way to make our webapp stateful.

As cookies can be created both in javascript (frontend) and from http response (by backend), so is there any principle when cookies should be created by frontend and when by backend?

Is some user scenario can be given, it would be great.

Answer (score 27):

There are a few considerations:

1. Where is the content for the cookie created?  If it's a session id, then that's probably created on the server so the cookie would be created there.  If it's a user viewing preference that isn't stored server-side, then that's probably set in the client and the cookie would be set there.
2. Server-side cookies can be set with additional security (called http-only) that makes them visible only to servers, not to client-side javascript, but they are still stored by browsers to represent a particular client.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing. Use whatever is convenient. Like if you do something in JS (in front-end) and you want to store cookie, store it from JS. Same for the back-end.

This may help.

- [Cookies - PHP vs Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281795/cookies-php-vs-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that server side code is executed before client side code.

I came across this situation:

My backend code tracks each movement on website and indicator for visitor is a cookie. However, for initial visit, when user doesn't have cookie, my function will save that movement with indicator `undefined` because user request is handled before cookie generation.

So in this case, I would go with backend for cookies.

In the meantime, I like to create cookies on client side when I need to fix broken WordPress website and I use external Node.JS API as glue.