# Can't get cookie expiration time in golang

Tags: http, cookies, go

I'm setting a new cookie

```
func f1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
...
expire := time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0)
cookie := http.Cookie{"token", token, "/", "domain", expire, expire.Format(time.UnixDate), 86400, true, true, "token=" + token, []string{"token=" + token}}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

Then i'm trying to get it

```
func f2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
...
cookie, err := r.Cookie("token")
fmt.Println(cookie.Value)
fmt.Println(cookie.Expires)
```

Output

```
valid_token_string
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Value is the same i set, but Expires is empty.
Why?

Comment: Just as an aside: the `RawExpires`, `Raw`, and `Unparsed` fields of `Cookie` are not used when setting cookies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's how HTTP works; the expires attribute is only sent with the Set-Cookie response header, not with the Cookie request header. The Cookie request header contains only the names and values of the cookies, not any other metadata.

Comment: Documentations says: SetCookie adds a Set-Cookie header to the provided ResponseWriter's headers.
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: @spe I don't see how that's relevant. You're using `Cookie`, which reads a cookie from a request. `SetCookie` sets a cookie for a response.

Comment: I see. So, is it is not possible to get cookie expiration time on server side, right?

Comment: No. The data is unavailable so you can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few minutes to figure out how to use the expiry time.

I feel this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29595232/18864864) is not enough.
I would like to add 2 more points to this:

1. Server-side cookies can be set with additional security (called http-only) that makes them visible only to servers, not to client-side javascript, but they are still stored by browsers to represent a particular client. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082511/which-way-to-create-cookie-by-frontend-or-backend)
2. When backend sets this cookie with an expiration time, The browser deletes the cookie as soon as it is expired.

I believe that is how it works with expiration.
If we store a session token, backend is going to check for session expiry anyway.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to query the expiry, you should address it as a different cookie.