# Golang: SetCookie doesn't update expiration

Tags: go

I have the following code and works fine:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", samplePage)
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func samplePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "username", Value: "XXX", Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    fmt.Fprintln(w, cookie.Value)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, cookie.Expires)
}
```

It gives me

```
XXX
2016-03-29 17:57:02.7077906 -0700 PDT
```

However, if I print the following, it doesn't work:

```
cookie2, err := r.Cookie("username")
checkErr(err) //no error is found
fmt.Fprintln(w, cookie2.Value)
fmt.Fprintln(w, cookie2.Expires)
```

This gives me

```
XXX
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Looks like the "Value" works but "Expires" doesn't. I would like to use Cookie for user login. Could anyone tell me how to make "cookie2" work?

p.s. I also found the following question: [Can't get cookie expiration time in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595154/cant-get-cookie-expiration-time-in-golang) It is very similar to my problem but the answer says we cannot use cookie in this way. If this is true then may I know how everyone is using cookie?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see a difference between this question and the question you linked. Call [http.SetCookie](https://godoc.org/net/http#SetCookie) to set a cookie on a response. Most applications should set the cookie path. Use [Request.Cookie](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Cookie) to get a cookie from a request.  The Name and Value fields are the only fields set in these cookies (because that's all the client sends).  Because browser clients do not send expired cookies, there's usually not a reason for the server to know the expiration time.

Comment: oh~~~ so do you mean that if a cookie with expire=10 seconds is sent to client with SetCookie, the timer is on and client cookie will expire after 10 seconds? And after 10 seconds the client no longer carry this cookie to do request? If it's true it makes a lot of sense~

Comment: Browsers do not send cookies after the cookie has expired, but do not depend on this for security.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get cookie expiration time in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595154/cant-get-cookie-expiration-time-in-golang)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helped.

Answer (score -1):

You should request the cookie with name "Expiry" and you'll get the expiry you have set